# Read variable and function from injected js script from content-script

Tags: javascript, function, variables, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I inject an script from content-script like

**content-script.js**

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
// TODO: add "script.js" to web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('latest.js');
s.onload = function(){
   console.log(test);
}
(document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

**latest.js**

```
var test = 1000;
```

It added properly, but now my problem is to read variables and functions from the latest.js on content script because content-script having some data which need to pass in the latest.js via using its functions or variables.

So, onload function I try to console.log(test) which is define in latest.js but I cannot be used it, its undefined.

Help me!!!

Comment: `chrome.extension.getURL` doesn't work in a content script - you need to look into [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) perhaps

Comment: that's working fine, my problem is to read the variable which is in the latest.js

Comment: oh, I didn't realise you can do that, sorry ... perhaps you need to wait for the `s.onload` to happen, then the content of `latest.js` will have been parsed by the JS engine, and any code/vars in that file will be "available" - it really depends on the content of `latest.js`

Comment: the `onload` event is firing, try `window.test = 1000;` in the script instead - just as a test

Comment: looks like https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment is the issue - which comes back to using [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) - though, that will make "functions" a little harder to "get" - I wonder if using fetch/XHR, creating an empty script node and adding the content would work

Comment: @JaromandaX its not working.. inside onload I also put setTimeout but still its not working.

Comment: what do you mean fetch/XHR ? can you explain it little bit more. what I need to do

Comment: [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) ... I find it incredulous that you are creating a web extension, yet you don't know about these - not saying it will work though, just thinking of alternatives as you say that the code you've tried (which looks technically correct) doesn't work

Comment: You misunderstand me, I said that under unload function window.test is not working. And I know about XHR but I said that what do want to do with XHR here.. give an some example or hint to implement XHR here..

Comment: `under unload function window.test is not working` - ignore my fetch/xhr suggestions - you will probably need to use message passing after all

Comment: do you have any example or code ?

Comment: isn't there examples in the message passing link I posted already?

Answer (score 0):

According chrome extensions [docs about a content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts):

> ...content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>   Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
>   Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts

So, your `latest.js` ejects to restricted area and content-script cannot directly read that data.

But the documentation also provides a solution: to communicate via `.postMessage`.

[Example from the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication):

**content-script**

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect();

window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  // We only accept messages from ourselves
  if (event.source != window)
    return;

  if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "FROM_PAGE")) {
    console.log("Content script received: " + event.data.text);
    port.postMessage(event.data.text);
  }
}, false);
```

**injected** script (latest.js in your case)

```
document.getElementById("theButton").addEventListener("click",
    function() {
  window.postMessage({ type: "FROM_PAGE", text: "Hello from the webpage!" }, "*");
}, false);
```